# Pandoc LuaLatex error: cannot find image file

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I've recently started having a weird error when converting a file from markdown to PDF, namely when using LuaLatex as the PDF engine and including some PDF images in the markdown file.

Running `pandoc -i 1384e7d0c2.md -o test.pdf --pdf-engine=lualatex` on a Markdown file with PDF images yields the following error:

```
Error producing PDF.
! error:  (file "/tmp/tex2pdf.-f23128305f8b8fe3/""c683e86dfecf4c7ba8f65730919b05
50d0deef84".pdf) (pdf backend): cannot find image file '"/tmp/tex2pdf.-f23128305
f8b8fe3/""c683e86dfecf4c7ba8f65730919b0550d0deef84".pdf'
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

All of the images are included in this format: `![MSb / LSb diagram](diagrams/19-07-10_23-23-44.pdf)`.

It seems like LuaLatex is adding " and ' characters to the paths that shouldn't be there, but I am not sure about what to do to remedy this.

Comment: i'm having the same problem with plain lualatex